# firefox font rendering incorrectly

Tags: font-face, frontend, webfonts

I'm having trouble with my website's font rendering. The logo font renders correctly in chrome and safari but, not in firefox.

This is the css code:

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Bello Pro';
  src: url('./Bello Pro.otf');
}

.logo {
  font-family: 'Bello Pro';
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your version of Firefox supports both `@font-face`, and your font format. You may also want to check the permissions, sometimes firefox won't render fonts according to origin policies, and/or certain formats.

You should use an online font converter and provide ALL formats of your font (otf, ttf, eot, woff, svg).

Comment: P.S., I deleted my other answer because I misread your question the first time. I thought you were saying firefox was rendering it badly, not not rendering it at all.

Comment: Hi, it is rendering in firefox but, it just isn't using the font I specified its using a default arial font. But in chrome and safari it is bello pro

Comment: Right, as Firefox would if the font resource isn't there. Do you have firebug? If so try to inspect for any errors in the debugger and see if you can find anything.

Comment: Hi, I've solved this problem now. I just moved the font .otf file into a different directory and now its working. Thanks for your help